# chef-client node name must be identical to client name?

Tags: chef-infra

i am able to run "chef-client" command to my hosted chef server using the following command:

> sudo chef-client -c /etc/chef/knife.rb -o 'role[webserver]'

and this knife.rb file:

```
 node_name                "my_client_name"  
 client_key               "#{current_dir}/my_client_name.pem"
 validation_client_name   "XXXXX-validator"
 validation_key           "#{current_dir}/XXXXX-validator.pem"  
 chef_server_url          "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/XXXXX"
```

BUT, when I am trying to use a different node name in the file or by using the -N in the command I get:

> Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for
>   "aaaa"   Failed to authenticate to the chef server (http 401).
>   Invalid signature for user or client 'aaaa'

seems that only when the node name is identical to the client name the command runs successfully.

I guess I am missing something but I would like to have the NODE name to be the $HOSTNAME or any name other than the client name. what am I missing?

Thanks,
Amos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bootstrap new node on hosted chef, you basically creates client and node.

By official documentation node is:

```
any physical, virtual, or cloud machine that is configured to be maintained by a chef-client
```

And client is used for authentication with chef server (its represented with RSA public key-pairs).

So by default client and node names are the same, and because of that you can't change name name on fly.

To change it you must destroy current node and create a new one, with bootstrap command, or manually create node and client with:

```
  knife client create #{name} --file client_keys/#{name}.pem -d
  knife node create #{name} -u #{name} -k client_keys/#{name}.pem -d
```

For more info check official docs:

- Clinet https://docs.getchef.com/knife_client.html
- Node https://docs.getchef.com/knife_node.html